# does it make sense to browserify polymer elements` js?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, polymer, browserify

I'm building a project that uses browserify and would now like to add polymer for custom elements. (I'm using grunt for automated builds)

Polymer is rather opinionated about the way custom elements are defined. It seems to make a lot of sense from a modularity point of view to have everything belonging to an element in the same file.

On the other hand browerify should manage all javascript dependencies and code... so my question is basically: where is the optimum for large projects (e.g. web platforms)?

Thanks!